# installing linux kernel headers for Debian 2.6.32-48 squeeze 6

Tags: linux

I cannot install the kernel header package for debian.  Its not found with apt-get install, even 'apt-cache search linux-headers' yields no results for my version.
My sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64 (2.6.32-48squeeze6) https://archive.debian.net/squeeze/linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64 ... linux-image-2.6.32-5-686 (2.6.32-48squeeze6) https://archive.debian.net/squeeze/linux-image-2.6.32-5-686 .... Ref. Google, https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=linux-2.6+2.6.32-48squeeze6 ...

Comment: this didnt come up when i searched!  put this as the answer so can mark it off